# Use AMPScript to assign vouchers

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to write some AMPscript to assign vouchers to all customers for every variation of country and language.

I can make it work for a segment of the customers but not for every variation of language and country even the logic is pretty straightforward, I can't figured out what I'am doing wrong

SubscriberKey is the same as CustomerID

[image: BFBBV-EN-2019 - data extension]

[image: Black Friday Voucher – Email Send 6th December]

[image]

```
    %%[
      set @BFBBVSubscriber = Lookup("Black Friday Voucher – Email Send 6th December", "SubscriberKey", "SubscriberKey", @CustomerID)

      if (@CustomerID == @BFBBVSubscriber) then

      ]%%

      %%[/* UK targeting */
      if ((@lang=='en' and (@prefcountry==1 or empty(@prefcountry))) or ((@lang=='us' or @lang=='au' or @lang=='nz') and @prefcountry==1)) then 

      set @couponCode = ClaimRowValue("BFBBV-EN-2019","CouponCode","IsClaimed","None Available","SubscriberKey",@CustomerID)
      ]%%

      <!-- UK Content Start -->


           %%=v(@CouponCode)=%%


      <!-- UK Content End -->


      %%[ /* AU targeting */
      elseif ((@lang=='au' and (@prefcountry==27 or empty(@prefcountry))) or ((@lang=='us' or @lang=='en' or @lang=='nz') and @prefcountry==27) or (@prefcountry==29)) then 

      set @couponCode = ClaimRowValue("BFBBV-AU-2019","CouponCode","IsClaimed","None Available","SubscriberKey",@CustomerID)
      ]%%


      <!-- AU Content Start -->


           %%=v(@CouponCode)=%%


      <!-- AU Content End -->


      %%[ /* US targeting */
      elseif ((@lang=='us' and (@prefcountry==18 or empty(@prefcountry))) or ((@lang=='au' or @lang=='en' or @lang=='nz') and @prefcountry==18)) then 

      set @couponCode = ClaimRowValue("BFBBV-US-2019","CouponCode","IsClaimed","None Available","SubscriberKey",@CustomerID)
      ]%%

      <!-- US Content Start -->


           %%=v(@CouponCode)=%%


      <!-- US Content End -->


      %%[ /* NZ targeting */
      elseif ((@lang=='nz' and (@prefcountry==35 or empty(@prefcountry))) or ((@lang=='au' or @lang=='en' or @lang=='us') and @prefcountry==35) or (@prefcountry==38)) then 

      set @couponCode = ClaimRowValue("BFBBV-NZ-2019","CouponCode","IsClaimed","None Available","SubscriberKey",@CustomerID)
      ]%%

      <!-- NZ Content Start -->


           %%=v(@CouponCode)=%%


      <!-- NZ Content End -->


      %%[ /* DE targeting */
      elseif (@lang=='de') then

      set @couponCode = ClaimRowValue("BFBBV-EUR-2019","CouponCode","IsClaimed","None Available","SubscriberKey",@CustomerID)
      ]%%

      <!-- DE Content Start -->


           %%=v(@CouponCode)=%%


      <!-- DE Content End -->


      %%[ /* ES targeting */
      elseif (@lang=='es') then 

      set @couponCode = ClaimRowValue("BFBBV-EUR-2019","CouponCode","IsClaimed","None Available","SubscriberKey",@CustomerID)
      ]%%

      <!-- ES Content Start -->


           %%=v(@CouponCode)=%%


      <!-- ES Content End -->


      %%[ /*FR targeting */
      elseif (@lang=='fr') then 

      set @couponCode = ClaimRowValue("BFBBV-EUR-2019","CouponCode","IsClaimed","None Available","SubscriberKey",@CustomerID)
      ]%%

      <!-- FR Content Start -->


           %%=v(@CouponCode)=%%


      <!-- FR Content End -->


      %%[ /* IT targeting */
      elseif (@lang=='it') then 

      set @couponCode = ClaimRowValue("BFBBV-EUR-2019","CouponCode","IsClaimed","None Available","SubscriberKey",@CustomerID)
      ]%%

      <!-- IT Content Start -->


           %%=v(@CouponCode)=%%


      <!-- IT Content End -->


      %%[ /* JP targeting */
      elseif (@lang=='ja') then 

      set @couponCode = ClaimRowValue("BFBBV-JP-2019","CouponCode","IsClaimed","None Available","SubscriberKey",@CustomerID)
      ]%%

      <!-- JP Content Start -->


           %%=v(@CouponCode)=%%


      <!-- JP Content End -->


      %%[ /* NL targeting */
      elseif (@lang=='nl') then 

      set @couponCode = ClaimRowValue("BFBBV-EUR-2019","CouponCode","IsClaimed","None Available","SubscriberKey",@CustomerID)
      ]%%

      <!-- NL Content Start -->


           %%=v(@CouponCode)=%%


      <!-- NL Content End -->


      %%[ /* RU targeting */
      elseif (@lang=='ru') then 

      set @couponCode = ClaimRowValue("BFBBV-RU-2019","CouponCode","IsClaimed","None Available","SubscriberKey",@CustomerID)
      ]%%

      <!-- RU Content Start -->


           %%=v(@CouponCode)=%%


      <!-- RU Content End -->


      %%[ /* SV targeting */
      elseif (@lang=='sv') then 

      set @couponCode = ClaimRowValue("BFBBV-SV-2019","CouponCode","IsClaimed","None Available","SubscriberKey",@CustomerID)
      ]%%

      <!-- SV Content Start -->


           %%=v(@CouponCode)=%%


      <!-- SV Content End -->


      %%[ /* ZH targeting */
      elseif (@lang=='zh') then 

      set @couponCode = ClaimRowValue("BFBBV-CNY-2019","CouponCode","IsClaimed","None Available","SubscriberKey",@CustomerID)
      ]%%

      <!-- ZH Content Start -->


           %%=v(@CouponCode)=%%


      <!-- ZH Content End -->


      %%[ /* ROW/EN */
      elseif (@CustomerID == @BFBBVSubscriber) then

      set @couponCode = ClaimRowValue("BFBBV-EN-2019","CouponCode","IsClaimed","None Available","SubscriberKey",@CustomerID)
      ]%%

      <!-- EN Content Start -->


           %%=v(@CouponCode)=%%


      <!-- EN Content End -->



      %%[endif]%%

      %%[endif]%%
```

Answer (score 1):

I have shortened the script and made some comments.

Maybe this helps you but please leave a comment because i am not totally sure that i covered the aspect you wanted an solution for.

```
%%[
/* We do not know how you set @prefcountry therefore we do not know if the empty function can be used*/
/* empty function only works reliably when you set the value with AttributeValue() like set @prefcountry = AttributeValue("ColumnName")*/

set @BFBBVSubscriber = Lookup("Black Friday Voucher – Email Send 6th December", "SubscriberKey", "SubscriberKey", @CustomerID)

if (@CustomerID == @BFBBVSubscriber) then   
    /* UK targeting */
    if ((@lang=='en' and (@prefcountry==1 or empty(@prefcountry))) or ((@lang=='us' or @lang=='au' or @lang=='nz') and @prefcountry==1)) then 
        set @couponCode = ClaimRowValue("BFBBV-EN-2019","CouponCode","IsClaimed","None Available","SubscriberKey",@CustomerID)
    /* AU targeting */
    elseif ((@lang=='au' and (@prefcountry==27 or empty(@prefcountry))) or ((@lang=='us' or @lang=='en' or @lang=='nz') and @prefcountry==27) or (@prefcountry==29)) then 
        set @couponCode = ClaimRowValue("BFBBV-AU-2019","CouponCode","IsClaimed","None Available","SubscriberKey",@CustomerID)
    /* US targeting */
    elseif ((@lang=='us' and (@prefcountry==18 or empty(@prefcountry))) or ((@lang=='au' or @lang=='en' or @lang=='nz') and @prefcountry==18)) then 
        set @couponCode = ClaimRowValue("BFBBV-US-2019","CouponCode","IsClaimed","None Available","SubscriberKey",@CustomerID)
    /* NZ targeting */
    elseif ((@lang=='nz' and (@prefcountry==35 or empty(@prefcountry))) or ((@lang=='au' or @lang=='en' or @lang=='us') and @prefcountry==35) or (@prefcountry==38)) then 
        set @couponCode = ClaimRowValue("BFBBV-NZ-2019","CouponCode","IsClaimed","None Available","SubscriberKey",@CustomerID)
    /* Europe targeting */
    elseif @lang=='de' or @lang=='es' or @lang=='fr' or @lang=='it' or @lang=='nl' then
        set @couponCode = ClaimRowValue("BFBBV-EUR-2019","CouponCode","IsClaimed","None Available","SubscriberKey",@CustomerID)
    elseif (@lang=='ja') then 
        set @couponCode = ClaimRowValue("BFBBV-JP-2019","CouponCode","IsClaimed","None Available","SubscriberKey",@CustomerID)
    /* RU targeting */
    elseif (@lang=='ru') then 
        set @couponCode = ClaimRowValue("BFBBV-RU-2019","CouponCode","IsClaimed","None Available","SubscriberKey",@CustomerID)
    /* SV targeting */
    elseif (@lang=='sv') then 
         set @couponCode = ClaimRowValue("BFBBV-SV-2019","CouponCode","IsClaimed","None Available","SubscriberKey",@CustomerID)
    /* ZH targeting */
    elseif (@lang=='zh') then 
         set @couponCode = ClaimRowValue("BFBBV-CNY-2019","CouponCode","IsClaimed","None Available","SubscriberKey",@CustomerID)
    /* ROW/EN */

    /* The following if clause if totally senseless. You can only enter this state when you fullfilled the condition previously, checking it again is redudant*/
    /* elseif (@CustomerID == @BFBBVSubscriber) then*/
    /*    set @couponCode = ClaimRowValue("BFBBV-EN-2019","CouponCode","IsClaimed","None Available","SubscriberKey",@CustomerID)*/
    /* You do not have a ELSE clause which I strongly advice in basicly any (only very few not) scenario, you always have to make sure you thought about every aspect*/
    /* Even when the else statement would be nothing i would still include it */
    else
        set @couponCode = ClaimRowValue("BFBBV-EN-2019","CouponCode","IsClaimed","None Available","SubscriberKey",@CustomerID)
    endif
/* You do not have a ELSE clause which I strongly advice in basicly any (only very few not) scenario, you always have to make sure you thought about every aspect */
/* Even when the else statement would be nothing i would still include it */
else
    /* Seems there shouldn't be done anything, maybe raiserror or sth? */
endif
]%%

%%=v(@couponCode)=%%
```